# What's a better way of saying : "Put out a fire by waving your hands in front of the flame"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a good expression to describe putting out a candle by waving your hands in front it? When you wave your hand, it creates a draft of air, and that air puts out the candle. How do you say that? "Waving your hands" doesn't seem right.

"He put out the fire by fanning with his hands." How does that sound?

Comment: I've never heard of that way of doing it, so I doubt if there is a standard expression. People usually blow out a candle, use a conical extinguisher or pinch the wick with moistened fingers.

Comment: Is this literally about putting out a candle or is it a metaphor or idiom for something else? If it's not literal, you'll need to provide more information on how it's used.

Comment: Are you talking about a Kung Fu thing? http://www.kungfumagazine.com/forum/showthread.php?52532-Candle-training/page3&s=2a452c7a3b9c627c1b86d3a005b057bb

Comment: So when you wave your hand, it creates draft of air, and that air douses the candle.

Comment: A candle and a fire are two different things.  The expression in the title seems to indicate a desperate or futile effort to do something. Something like trying to put out a forest-fire by pissing on it.

Comment: @Jim I have no idea where you got that. Black Dagger clearly states that a fire is being doused by the action. And while candles and fires are two separate things, they're not trying to put out a pillar of wax any more than a forest fire. They mean a small flame, which is easily extinguished by the motion.

Comment: @lly - My point is, taken in isolation, I would never have guessed that the intent of the phrase in the title was about the name for the action of blowing out a candle by over-fanning it.

Comment: Maybe you’ve ***overdrafted*** it.  :-)

Comment: How about "futile handwaving"?

Answer (score 1):

## There isn't one

as far as the *OED* knows. I mean, there are *scads* of synonyms for "extinguish"—*out*, *outen*, *dout*, *kill*, *redd*, a horde of variants of *slake*, &c.—and you could just pick an obscure one to use with your special sense.

Really, though, the default way to coin a new expression for *putting* or *doing out* a fire is exactly that: take whatever action or device you're using and add *out* to it. I like the irony of using **fan out** for putting out a fire but that expression does already have a separate meaning.

Comment: "He put out the fire by fanning with his hands." How does that sound?

Comment: @BlackDagger Sounds completely off. You could have it work by using *out* but *fanning a flame* with no interrupting preposition is going to mean making the flame bigger by feeding it air.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the past participle of the verb “swish” which means “move with a hissing or rushing sound”:

> He swished his hand to blow out the candle flame.

I suppose you could use “waved” instead of “swished” here too:

> He waved his hand to blow out the candle flame.

Hope that helps.